# Is there an alternative solution to replace the use of isNotDisplayed() methods in the code after migrating Chrome to FedCM?

Tags: google-chrome, google-one-tap, fedcm

After migrating Chrome to FedCM, the use of **isDisplayMoment(), isDisplayed(), isNotDisplayed(), and getNotDisplayedReason()** methods in the code has been discontinued, making it impossible to monitor the component status using these methods.

Is there any alternative solution available to replace the aforementioned monitoring methods?